# foreach loop by primitive or by boxed class in Java

Tags: java, generics, collections, boxing, unboxing

Currently I am reading a book "Java Generics and Collections" and I have found an interesting code:

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
int s = 0;
for (int n : ints) { s += n; }
assert s == 6;
```

Here foreach loop iterate over primitives:

```
for (int n : ints) { ... }
```

However, Eclipse IDE suggests me to iterate over boxed type:

```
for (Integer n : ints) { ... }
```

Are there any benefits of using one or another style of iterating?

Comment: collection doesn't support primitive types , so there are wrapper class to use primitives in collections.

Comment: generics are removed at runtime, so your list is populated with objects. On retrieval they are cast back to `Integer`. When you iterate over the list with `int` values, you force the unboxing to be done for every iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boxing/unboxing has a cost at runtime.

- if you are going to unbox the `Integer` once within the body of your loop, like you do, it won't make much of a difference.
- if you unbox the `Integer` many times in the body of your loop, you would be better off unboxing it once with `for(int i : ints)`
- if you are going to use an Integer in the body of your loop, then using `int` would lead to an unnecessary unbox/box operation.

For example:

```
List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Integer i : ints) { //better not to unbox
  if (someCondition(i)) subList.add(i);
}

for (int i : ints) { //better to unbox once
  int a = i;
  int b = 2 * i;
  sum += a + b - i;
}
```

Comment: and if yo are using `int` instead of `Integer` then it will also cause faster execution if collection is of huge size.

Comment: Your answer is useful, however what if there are many places in the loop where "Integer i" is going to be unboxed(e.g. sum is calculated together with other arithmetic operations)? Is not is better to use for (int n : ints)?

Comment: @DmytroPlekhotkin In that case it is better to unbox once with `for (int i : ints)` of course.

Comment: @Prashant I don't understand your point. Never unboxing the Integer is better than unboxing it, regardless of the size of the collection...

Comment: @assylias: i was simply saying that if collection is huge, Several Integer object will be created.

Comment: @Prashant Ah ok - but that's a different discussion: if you want to use one of the JDK's collections you have no other choice than using Integers. If you want to stick to ints you will have to use another library or go back to arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
    List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3); //here lists is of type Integer which is boxed type
    int s = 0; //s is primitive type
```

Remember we can compare only:

1.) a primitive to a primitive type

2.) Boxed to a Boxed type

we can say

List ints  can be represented  as :

```
    [Integer.valueof(1), Integer.valueof(2), Integer.valueof(3)]
```

So, in following code

```
    for (int n : ints) // in every loop ints current index value which is an Integer is unboxed and assigned to 'int n'
```

and when the following code is read..

```
     s += n;// int n is added to int s (primitive added to primitive ie; no conversion done here)
```

2.) Now the second approach

```
    for (Integer n : ints) { ... }// here, since 'n' is also boxed so no conversion takes place
```

However, when following line is encountered

```
    s += n; // boxed Integer n is unboxed to a primitive and added to primitive 's' (so unboxing/conversion happens in each addition)
```

So, that is the difference between the two however, the number of conversions in the both the approaches are same.